# Average of the Möbius function over the values $p-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering whether this result is in the bibliography and how one might go about proving it: $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x }{x} \sum_{p \leq x \atop p\text{ prime }}\mu(p-1)=0.$$ The sum is taken  over all primes $p\leq x $.

Comment: I have a sinking feeling that this might be twin-prime-conjecture hard.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this may imply that if there are two non negative integers $a$ et $b$ such that the number of negative values of the summand is $\sim ax$ and the number of positive values thereof is $\sim bx$, then $a=b$. This may be related to RH.

Comment: The same conclusion holds replacing mutatis mutandis $x$ by $\pi(x)$ in the considered asymptotics.

Comment: I recommend to search for "multiplicative functions on shifted primes"
I found a paper by Hildebrand, Additive and Multiplicative Functions on Shifted Primes, Proc London Math. Soc. 1989,
https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-59.2.209
where it is mentioned that this type of problem with the Liouville $\lambda$ function is open, but might follow from a Halasz Thm on shifted primes.

Theorems 1 and 3 go a step in the direction you want.